# Inconsistent behaviour of Angular JS number filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

This might sound strange at beginning but trust me I have seen this happening:

I had the following piece of Angular code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in list">
                                    <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                                    <td ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">{{i.data[x] | number}}</td>
                                    <td>{{i.Yield| number}}</td>
                                    <td>{{i.Total | number}}</td>
                                </tr>
```

I faced a strange issue with above code. When the data array was having null for few indexes, I was expecting them to be displayed as null (nothing), as per API documentation. Even if the null is parsed in JS as zero, one can expect to see zero at places of null.

But I found a random behaviour when few index were converted to zero and few remained null. I could not identify any pattern for this.

More strange is the fact that the values changed from zero to null or null to zero, even after the page has been loaded, which gives me an indication of any digest cycle running and updating the values.

Just to make proper restriction I modified above code as following

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in list">
                            <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                            <td ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">{{i.data[x] != null ? (i.data[x] | number) : ''}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.Yield === null ? '' : i.Yield | number}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.Total === null ? '' : i.Total | number}}</td>
                        </tr>
```

but still the issue stands the same. I have tried looking out for any blunder on my end, but looks all is fine from my side. The data is surely null, there are no other checks applied which might result in this behaviour; none that I could see yet.

Is there anyone out there who has faced anything of this sort before.

Comment: You can create an example on jsfiddle that would reproduce the problem?

Comment: Have you tried <td ng-repeat="item in i.data | limitTo : 12">{{item != null ? item : ''| number }}</td>

Comment: @jbrown Nope, not tried it yet..How is it suppose to make any changes anyways?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will resolve your problem but the ng-repeat="x in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]" is really odd code.  I probably can't help you solve the problem without seeing the contents of list.  @StepanKasyanenko suggestion of a jsfiddle is a good idea.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @jbrown. Well it converts all nulls to zero now, however I am looking to display null as blank

Comment: Will try to replicate the issue using JSFiddle..

Comment: If you change your null condition to NaN, you'll get the desired result.  {{item != null ? item: NaN | number }}

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to:

```
 <td ng-repeat="item in i.data | limitTo : 12">{{item != null ? item : NaN | number }} </td>
```

The angular number filter with return blank for NaN but not for an empty string ('')